# TFS, Source code, SharePoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I add my Sharepoint project as source code into TFS? I have the original directory in my host machine, and I make it as a shared folder between the host and VM.

When I try to debug the Sharepoint project (on VM) and deploy my changes, then attach the w3wp processes and start the web page, the "Service is unavailable" message appears.

How can I deploy my changes on the project and work on my project as a source code?

Comment: Are you asking how to get your project into TFS or how to deploy to SharePoint from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are experiencing isn't directly related to TFS or Source Control. In order to add your project to source control, you just need to open it and select "Add to Source Control". I recommend doing this from your host machine.

For a smooth operation, you should first create proper workspace mappings in TFS and put your project inside a TFS workspace. Please check this for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138514(v=vs.90).aspx

You should probably post the "Service is unavailable" part of your question to a Sharepoint forum since it's unrelated to source control.